# Add a column to a table with check constraint SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, constraints, alter

I want to add a column to a table, then add a check constraint to make sure its greater than 0. I cant seem to get this to run in oracle sl developer.

```
Alter TABLE store101
add column Base_salary Number(7,2)
constraint store101_Base_salary_ck
check (Base_salary > 0);
```

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `ADD COLUMN` clause in [`ALTER TABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53124) syntax. It's just `ADD`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE store101
ADD Base_salary NUMBER(7, 2) -- there is no need to add COLUMN clause
CONSTRAINT store101_Base_salary_ck 
CHECK (Base_salary > 0);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7663/1)** demo

Comment: That solved it thanks for your help and patience with my lack of knowledge