# How do I add a not null column and a check constraint in one line in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to add a new INTEGER column to a table. The column must be NOT NULL, with a default value of 1, and only accept values greater than zero.

I'm trying to do this at the moment:

```
ALTER TABLE FOO_AUTHORS 
ADD PUBLICATION_PERIOD_DAYS INTEGER DEFAULT(1) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT publicationPeriodDays 
CHECK (PUBLICATION_PERIOD_DAYS>0);
```

Is there a way to do this in one line? I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542695/103378) example, but it's not working because of the NOT NULL. Is the NOT NULL then necessary?

I'm getting the following error from the DB:

> QL Error: ORA-02293: cannot validate (DBOWNER.PUBLICATIONPERIODDAYS) - check constraint violated
>   02293. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
>   *Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
>              populated table that had nocomplying values.

If I try it without the NOT NULL, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roll the `NOT NULL` constraint into the `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE FOO_AUTHORS 
  ADD PUBLICATION_PERIOD_DAYS INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  CONSTRAINT publicationPeriodDays
  CHECK ( PUBLICATION_PERIOD_DAYS IS NOT NULL AND PUBLICATION_PERIOD_DAYS > 0 );
```

The existing rows will have their `PUBLICATION_PERIOD_DAYS` set to the default value.