# Oracle check constraint column either zero or unique

Tags: oracle, unique, check-constraints

I have to add a constraint to an Oracle table. A numeric column should be zero or unique(and >0).
I tried inserting queries inside the constraint definition or functions but they are no allowed.
Any idea?
Greetings, Marcelo.

Comment: can you show us the check constraint how it is ? and also show us the insert ? and DDL of table would be a plus

Comment: Why zero? What business rule is this constraint trying to enforce?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671008/how-do-i-add-a-not-null-column-and-a-check-constraint-in-one-line-in-oracle-11g  it seems you guyz work together

Comment: @XING - more likely, they are in the same class and have the same homework or take-home exam.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your need, you could use a function-based index to check uniqueness on only positive values.

For example:

```
SQL> create table checkUniqueTab(n number);

Table created.

SQL> create unique index i1 on checkUniqueTab( case when n > 0 then n end);

Index created.
```

Inserting different values work:

```
SQL> insert into checkUniqueTab values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into checkUniqueTab values (2);

1 row created.
```

Here I try to insert a duplicate positive value:

```
SQL> insert into checkUniqueTab values (1);
insert into checkUniqueTab values (1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ALEK.I1) violated
```

I can insert many rows with 0 value:

```
SQL> insert into checkUniqueTab values (0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into checkUniqueTab values (0);

1 row created.
```

The result:

```
SQL> select * from checkUniqueTab;

         N
----------
         1
         2
         0
         0
```

This assumes that you already have a constraint on your table to prevent inserting negative values.

Comment: This is quite a neat solution but it also permits duplicate negative values. So I think we still need a check constraint to enforce `(n >= 0)` .

Comment: @APC:You're right; I was assuming that such a constraint already exists on the table, but it's better to clarify. Going to edit